# ElasticSearch Indexing, Adding Fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I would like to use elastic search to index the JSON schema provided below

```
{
   "data": "etc",
   "metadata": {
      "foo":"bar",
      "baz": "etc"
   }
}
```

However the metadata can vary and I do not know all the fields that could be present. Is there a way to tell elastic search that if it sees a value in the metadata object to index it in a certain way? (I do know that all the values would be strings)

Thanks

Comment: If I get you correctly you dont need to do anything special, when a new field added elasticsearch will recognize it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that using [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#path-match-unmatch), basically like this:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "full_name": {
            "path_match": "metadata.*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "text"    <---- add your desired mapping here
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```